# Copy merged cells making target also a merged cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have a merged cells A1:B1
I would like to copy that merged cell, however i would like to have a source cell merged in the same way.

```
Sub Copy()

Sheet2.Range("A1").Copy
Sheet2.Range("A5").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

End Sub
```

Using this code I will paste value of A1 to A5, however A5 wont be merged with B5, and that is the result I am looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specifically tell the destination cell to become merged. And you can specify the merge area by counting the rows and columns of the source cell's merged area.

```vb
Sub Example()
    Dim Src As Range
    Set Src = Range("A1")
    
    Dim Dst As Range
    Set Dst = Range("A5")
    
    Dst.Value = Src.Value
    
    Dst.Resize(Src.MergeArea.Rows.Count, Src.MergeArea.Columns.Count).Merge
End Sub
```

For copying formatting, in addition to the code above, add these lines:

```vb
    Src.Copy
    Dst.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

But since you're copying values and formatting, its probably easier to copy the whole range instead of doing one and then the other:

```vb
Sub Example2()
    Dim Src As Range
    Set Src = Range("A1")
    
    Dim Dst As Range
    Set Dst = Range("A5")
    
    'Copy Src to Dst
    Src.Copy Dst
    
    'Merge Dst like Src
    Dst.Resize(Src.MergeArea.Rows.Count, Src.MergeArea.Columns.Count).Merge
    
    'The first row of Dst may accidentally change height during the copy/paste
    Dst.Rows(1).RowHeight = Src.Rows(1).RowHeight
End Sub
```

Comment: And is there any possibility to apart from value, copy the format of the merged cell?

Comment: @Thamiar I have updated my answer with examples about copying formatting.